# Issue passing global variables across scripts

Tags: php, html

I have a script called *login.php* which takes user information supplied via a form and checks whether the entered login information is valid.  If the information is not valid, the following code is called:

```
$GLOBALS['user_login_fail'] = true;
header('Location: ../index.php'); //this displays index.html
```

In *index.html*, there is an error message that is shown if the user entered invalid login information:

```
<?php 

if($GLOBALS['user_login_fail'] == true)
{
    echo '<div> Login credentials could not be verified </div>';
}
else
{
    echo "no error";
}
?>
```

However, after being redirected I get an error: **Notice: Undefined index: user_login_fail**.  What's wrong here?

Comment: *Note:* should probably use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_GLOBALS`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting global variables and session variables confused.

[Globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) exist everywhere in the current scope, but a browser redirect creates a new scope. [Session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) persist across browser redirects.

Try this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_login_fail'] = true;
```

and

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_login_fail']) && $_SESSION['user_login_fail']) {
    echo '<div> Login credentials could not be verified </div>';
} else {
    echo "no error";
}
```

Comment: Post as a separate answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems (as stated already) that you are confusing `$_GLOBALS` with `$_SESSION` in php.
I'll tell you straight away: **`$_GLOBALS`** are bad practice in php.

---

#### Why globals are bad

> When people talk about global variables in other languages it means something different to what it does in PHP. That's because variables aren't really global in PHP. The scope of a typical PHP program is one HTTP request. Session variables actually have a wider scope the PHP "global" variables because they typically encompass many HTTP requests.

- [Google search for: "Why php globals are bad"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=why%20php%20globals%20are%20bad&oq=why%20ph&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j69i60l2j0.1527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)
- [Why global state is the devil, and how to avoid using it](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it)
- [SO: Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

---

Basically you want to be using `$_SESSIONS`. That would be done like this:

As the validation part:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_login_fail'] = true;
header("Location: index.php");
```

And as your **`index.php`**

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_login_fail']) && $_SESSION['user_login_fail'] == TRUE) {
    echo '<div> Login credentials could not be verified </div>';
} else {
    echo "no error";
}
```